# NN: Loss goes down, plateaus, then goes down again

Tags: neural-networks

I was training a simple NN with 1 hidden layer for binary classification for a simple dataset (XOR). Later, I found that the loss goes down, plateaus then goes down again. Same goes with accuracy, it goes up, plateaus, then goes up again.

Here is the loss and accuracy:

[image: loss and accuracy]

I experimented with different number of hidden layers, different layer widths, different lr but the pattern persisted. I just want to know, what is the meaning of this pattern? Is something wrong with the model? Or should I not worry?

Comment: To understand the meaning, it may be worth making a new plot with 4 lines: each showing the accuracy in predicting one of the four output patterns (0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1). But yes, we see this kind of thing all the time.